# I want to rewrite phtml file in module-grouped-product

Tags: overrides, phtml

I am trying to rewrite the phtml file but it's not working my code is :

a main file path is `public_html/vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml`

my file path is `public_html/app/design/frontend/mytheme/themename/Magento_GroupedProduct /templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml`

I don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: this is right way of overriding .phtml, Did you run deployment script after overriding?

Comment: yes, I did it .